# Baseboard meeting at top of corner but not bottom

Tags: baseboard

Removed 3" and installing 4" baseboard. The inner corners meet at the top but gap at the bottom ( sheet rock taper is at the bottom and wondering if that's the problem) (have checked the saw and can't think of anything else).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Debbie

Comment: This is a normal problem, most home's are not square, but on a wide trim or a cheap saw you need to adjust your saw  OR fill the gap and paint over is. This is what contractors do. Cut long check and adjust or fill with wood putty.

Answer (score 2):

Baseboard should be installed using cope joints, not miters, for this exact reason. Some builders request that the drywall taping crew fill the edge channel on the drywall sheets along the floor to keep things more square, but this still doesn't resolve the issue of boards tightening outward when fastened, which very often results in open miters.

[Coping](http://www.familyhandyman.com/carpentry/trim-carpentry/how-to-cope-baseboard-trim-with-a-miter-saw/view-all), along with a slightly tensioned installation (cut 1/16" to 1/8" long, nail the ends first), almost always results in tight inside corners. This is crucial when working with natural wood, where fillers don't result in a quality appearance.

Comment: I agree if the wood is not going to be painted filler won't look right but no mater how hard we try to keep everything square there are usually a few corners that are slightly out of square, depending on the quality of the home really dictates what we used to do cheap track home some kind of filler, spec home usually much higher end adjust cut for perfection.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to take two test pieces and see which wall needs to be addressed.  Then drive a screw at the base in or out.  Check test pieces until they fit tight.  The screw keeps the bottom of the base from kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

There's frequently a taper on the bottom of the drywall where it meets the floor. In addition, the corner tape is sometimes a little thick down low. You might want to carve this away below the top line of the trim.

One solution is to shim (cardboard drywall shims would work) the bottom to prevent it from kicking in.

Alternately, you could only nail the top of the trim in the corner. This isn't the sturdiest solution, but it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you saw is square and true, thus, so are your joints, do the following (assuming its painted trim, and not finished wood)

1)  make the joint.  shim the top and/or bottom of each piece to get the corner to be tight top and bottom.  glue and nail the baseboards.

2)  inject latex caulking or drywall compound (if you have a sausage gun) into the top edge of the baseboard.  put enough in that its protruding a little bit from the joint.

3)  using a flexible 1 inch wide putty knife, place the 1 inch edge against the wall, and the blade vertical.  pull gently along the top of the trim until the filler starts to build up on the blade.  wipe off with a sponge and repeat.  do the whole piece this way.  if you do it carefully enough, you will have a perfect little square edged bead of filler that will dry to look like part of the trim.

4)  touch up the trim paint on to the bead of filler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you want to [cope](https://www.familyhandyman.com/carpentry/trim-carpentry/how-to-cope-joints/view-all/), it is the best way to get good corners.

Harry V got it right in his answer.

I found that great tip in [this](https://www.familyhandyman.com/carpentry/trim-carpentry/interior-trim-work-basics/view-all/) article in family handyman magazine on just this issue. 
[image]

The whole article is full of great stuff.

I subscribe to the magazine and always find useful info.